# Wordpress Custom Post Type Slug and duplicate content

Tags: wordpress, seo, custom-post-type

if we have Custom Post Type called services then by default slug in wordpress will be /service/post-name. But the weird thing is that post-name (same post) is also available without /service/ slug . So in browser if i type [www.domain.com/service/service-name](http://www.domain.com/service/service-name) and [www.domain.com/service-name](http://www.domain.com/service-name) its opening the same page? I want to avoid that because of SEO and duplciate content.  I only want /service/service-name to be available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, google crawlers check your sitemap, and in your `sitemap.xml` the address mentioned as `www.domain.com/service/service-name` they consider this page the main URL. And after 1-2 months if you check `www.domain.com/service-name` in your search console you will notice this page crawled but not indexed.
You may find your `sitemap.xml` in the following URL: `www.domain.com/sitemap.xml`

Comment: On most of the websites its not showing error in google search console. Because probably there is canonical tag that points to original url. However on one website i own google  search console show duplicate content error for those urls. In sitemap there is only page with /service/ slug but somehow google recognize / find the other one also.

Comment: In case you see a duplicate error, it is better to use a canonical tag. another suggestion is to add `.HTML` at the end of the URL and use `www.domain.com/service/service-slug.html` , based on my experience this format grow much faster.

Comment: Since permalink manager plugins change the permalink structure, if you use these plugins, like: `WooCommerce Permalink Manager`, it is better to add a canonical tag.

Comment: I am not using any plugin. CTP is created with custom code.

Comment: I had the same problem. Some plugins affect the permalink structure. In a clean WordPress website if you change the structure of the permalink in this URL `www.example.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` to `/%category%/%postname%/` you get 404 on `www.domain.com/service-name`.